# Can somebody tell me how I am using the class selector incorrectly?

Tags: html, css

HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel=“stylesheet” type=“text/css” href=“style.css” />
</head>

<body>

   <p>Red</p>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS file:

```
p {
   color: red;
}
```

The word 'Red' does not change to red text when I open the page in a browser. If anyone would know why my CSS file isn't linking to the HTML file that would be greatly appreciated. The files are in the same directory.

Comment: You're using it correctly.  Something else is likely wrong, like the stylesheet not being loaded.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/xnc5a4hh/)

Comment: I agree with @MichaelChaney. If you have stylesheets elsewhere in the document, try removing them as there may be another CSS rule overriding the one you mentioned.

Comment: That is all I have in the body of the .html file. There is only one stylesheet and that is the only line in the entire file.

Comment: Open the development tools in your browser and inspect the p element and check which styles are being applied.  Probably none.  Check the network tab in the dev tools and see why your stylesheet isn't loading.

Comment: Unless any of these answers help you, post all your code: the whole HTML file, the CSS file, their names and their file paths.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have provided has no errors.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9n97Lz69/

---

Please copy & paste the following code into your html file and verify this works:

index.html:

```
<style>
.menu p {
   color: red;
}
</style>

<div class="menu">
       <p>This sentence should be red.</p>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/21umj65u/

---

Then move the CSS to mystyle.css and verify this works:

index.html:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<div class="menu">
    <p>This sentence should be red.</p>
</div>
```

mystyle.css:

```
.menu p {
   color: red;
}
```

---

Please check the file location of `mystyle.css` and verify against the url in `index.html`:

index.html:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, perhaps "p" is already defined in your css file.Try this

```
.menu p {
   color: red !important;
}
```